# Linq compare 2 string arrays when both have same values

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 string arrays/values x,y and am trying to get values of y which are not in x. I am trying to get this value only in case if all values of x are also in y.

```
        string x = "CA ,WA";
        string y = "CA,WA,NY";
        var srcDetails = x.ToLower().Replace(" ", string.Empty).Split(',');
        var dstDetails = y.ToLower().Replace(" ", string.Empty).Split(',');

        var common = dstDetails.Intersect(srcDetails); //common in x,y

        var destGreaterSrc= dstDetails.Except(srcDetails); //if y > x

        var extraInDest = dstDetails.Except(common);
```

**extraInDest is extra value in y which is not in x**

In above code extra values in dest which is outputted as NY.

I am trying to find the scenario where values of x may not be equal to y like

```
    string x = "CA ,NV";
    string y = "CA,WA,NY";
```

how can we make var extraInDest output to false.

like var extraInDest = dstDetails.Except(common) resulting false or null

Comment: Will your string be always in CSV?

Comment: Always comma seperated.

Comment: string x = "CA ,WA";
            string y = "CA,WA,NY";
            var srcDetails = x.Split(',');
            var dstDetails = y.Split(',');

            var extraInSrc = srcDetails.Where(s => !dstDetails.Select(d => d.Trim().ToLower()).Contains(s.Trim().ToLower())).ToList();
            if (extraInSrc.Count() <= 0) // If all X values are present in Y
            {
                var extraInDst = dstDetails.Where(s => !srcDetails.Select(d => d.Trim().ToLower()).Contains(s.Trim().ToLower())).ToList();
            }

Comment: very interesting code block kashi.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest one would be

```
var extraInDest = srcDetails.Except(dstDetails).Any()
    ? null 
    : dstDetails.Except(srcDetails);
```

Comment: @Kurkula so does this one helped you?

Answer (score 1):

This should be simple, if your comparison should always result in a boolean value, you should use this instead

```js
bool extraInDest = srcDetails.All(v=>dstDetails.Contains(v));
```